# Accuracy falling down tensorflow v1.5

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-3.6

I'm using tensorflow 1.5 and keras 2.1.6. The code is taken from this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) and reworked to work on version 1.5. There is it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
               'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']


train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=['accuracy']);

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10);
```

But accuracy drops with every epoch and does not rise above 0.3. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Add adding more `Dense` layers. Also, it should be `tf.keras.layers.Dense(10 , activation='softmax' )` and not `tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)`.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal thank you very much! It's work now. Can you please explain, what 'softmax' change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you classifying images from the Fashion MNIST dataset, we need to set the activation function of the last `Dense` layer to `softmax`. The softmax function outputs probabilities for each of the 10 classes. Learn more about the softmax function [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/04/introduction-to-softmax-for-neural-network/).

Replace,

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
```

With,

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10 , activation='softmax' )
```